# problems with ArrayAdapter to show and object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the data from an object `Arraylist` that I have to show them on a Spinner.

Right now I have this:

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,R.array.cliente_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //recorrer los clientes, agregando el rut de cada uno de ellos al Array
        for (cs.matiasguzman.prueba_dos_final.Modelo.Cliente tmpCli:
                Cliente.manteCLi.getClientes()) {
            CharSequence cs= tmpCli.getRut();
            adapter.add(cs);
        }
        //set adapter al spinner
        spnCliente.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adpAparato= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.aparato_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spnDispositivo.setAdapter(adpAparato);

    }
```

The error is in the moment that I try `adapter.add(cs)`, I am trying to add Cliente or User in English to the Spinner.